# How to change a list depending on tkinter checkbutton

Tags: python, list, tkinter, checkbox

I have been trying to use tkinter CheckButton widget to edit items in a list - each item of the list is a new checkbutton. I want a save method to save the data to a text file, and a load method to load the info from the text file and mark the checkbutton boxes depending on the items in the list.

Here is my code so far, but the list doesn't seem to change when I check the buttons and update the list/file

Here is my code, I need to know why the list isn't updating when I check the boxes:

```
import tkinter.messagebox as box

modulesMain = Tk()
moduleChecks = []

def SaveChanges():
    # Clear the text file
    modules = open("modules.txt", "w") #Write mode to overwrite the whole file
    modules.write("") # Put in blank text
    modules.close()
    modules = open("modules.txt", "a") # Append mode to append the file
    for item in moduleChecks:
        modules.write(item + "\n")
    print(moduleChecks)



appButton = Checkbutton(modulesMain, text = "Test", variable = moduleChecks[0]).grid()
searchButton = Checkbutton(modulesMain, text = "Test", variable = moduleChecks[1]).grid()






Save = Button(modulesMain, text = "Save Changes", command = SaveChanges).grid()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: I've edited it slightly but my main question is not in the code it's in the rest of the text - there isn't an actual error it's just not doing anything to the list

Answer (score 0):

The variable for each of your checkboxes needs to be an `IntVar`. Your `moduleCheck` list is currently un-initialised so when you try to access the elements inside it, you'll get an error.

In the below code (modified from yours), I've initialised the `moduleCheck` to contain two IntVars.
When you press the save button, it will print to the console the current state of the check boxes.

```
import tkinter as tk

modulesMain = tk.Tk()
moduleChecks = [tk.IntVar() for i in range(2)]


def SaveChanges():
    for idx,item in enumerate(moduleChecks):
        print(f"{idx} = {item.get()}")

appCheck = tk.Checkbutton(modulesMain, text = "App", variable = moduleChecks[0])
appCheck.grid()
searchCheck = tk.Checkbutton(modulesMain, text = "Check", variable = moduleChecks[1])
searchCheck.grid()

saveButton = tk.Button(modulesMain, text = "Save Changes", command = SaveChanges)
saveButton.grid()

modulesMain.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it so when the program starts, it gets the info from a file, and automatically checks the right boxes (so how to add items to the list, and how to auto check the boxes

Comment: @MiniMinnow That sounds like a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#list of options. doubles as checkbox label text
#appending to this list is all that is necessary to create more options
opts = ['App', 'Search']

#create an StringVar for every option
#this way there doesn't have to be type conversions for reading/writing files
vars = [tk.StringVar(value='0') for _ in opts]

#create checkboxes for every option
for opt, var in zip(opts, vars):
    tk.Checkbutton(root, text=opt, variable=var, onvalue='1', offvalue='0').grid(sticky='w')

#write the checkbox values to file
def save_options_state():
    with open("modules.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(''.join([v.get() for v in vars]))

#set checkbox values from file            
def load_options_state():
    with open("modules.txt", "r") as file:
        for n, var in zip(list(file.read().strip()), vars):
            var.set(n)

#save/load buttons
tk.Button(root, text="save", command=save_options_state).grid()
tk.Button(root, text="load", command=load_options_state).grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a runnable example which I think shows how to do everything you've asked about. It assumes the `modules.txt` file contains data in the following format, where each line consists of a module's name and whether it's checked or not.

```
Mod1,0
Mod2,0
Mod3,0
```

The data in the file is used to create a list of `Checkbutton`s — one for each module — and initially sets to its current status as indicated in the file.

Here's the sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

dataFilename = "modules.txt"
moduleChecks = []

def ReadModules():
    with open(dataFilename, "r") as file:
        for line in (line.strip() for line in file):
            moduleName, moduleState = line.split(',')
            moduleChecks.append((moduleName, int(moduleState)))
    print('read:', moduleChecks)

def SaveChanges():
    print('writing:', moduleChecks)
    with open(dataFilename, "w") as file:
        for checkButton in moduleCheckbuttons:
            moduleName = checkButton.cget('text')
            moduleState = checkButton.var.get()
            file.write(','.join((moduleName, str(moduleState))) + '\n')

ReadModules()

modulesMain = Tk()
moduleCheckbuttons = []

# Create a Checkbutton for each module based on moduleChecks values.
for moduleName, moduleState in moduleChecks:
    intVar = IntVar(value=moduleState)
    checkButton = Checkbutton(modulesMain, text=moduleName, variable=intVar)
    checkButton.var = intVar  # Attach reference to variable.
    checkButton.grid()
    moduleCheckbuttons.append(checkButton)

saveButton = Button(modulesMain, text="Save Changes", command=SaveChanges)
saveButton.grid()

modulesMain.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mini: Doesn't this answer your question(s)?